# Sphere Coordinates

Tags: multivariable-calculus, spherical-coordinates

How do you convert the set $$ K = \{((x, y, z) \in \mathbb{R^3}
 | x^2 + y^2 + z^2 ≤ 25, -4 ≤ x ≤ 4, -4 ≤ y ≤ 4, -4 ≤ z ≤ 4)\} $$ into spherical coordinates?
It's evident that the radius ranges from 0 to 5, but what are the restrictions over phi and theta?

in my spherical conversion I got
$$  \;  0 ≤ r ≤ 5 \\ -4 \le r\sin\phi \sin\theta \le 4 \\ -4 \le r\sin\phi \cos\theta \le 4 \\ -4 \le r\cos\phi\le4$$

How do I proceed from here?

Thanks

Comment: Use the cartesian to spherical coordinate conversion to find the limits using $x=4$, $y=4$ and $z=4$ separately.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Hi. For your benefit write the trig functions in math with `\sin` and `\cos` which renders like $r \sin \phi \cos \theta$ for example.

Comment: What you have *is* a description of $K$ in spherical coordinates. There is no need to proceed from there. If we could find a rectangle for $\phi,\theta$ with fixed boundaries geometry would be all too simple.

Comment: @KurtG. Thank you for your answer. The main idea is to integrate over K using some function f in order to solve the integral , so there is a need to find a specific restrictions over r, phi , theta

Comment: What is the function $f$ you integrate?

Comment: @KurtG. $$f(x,y,z) = 3(x^2+y^2+z^2) $$

Comment: I would suggest you do the two-dimensional analog first, just to get more of a mastery of the approach. Second, work only with the portion of the object in the first octant ($x,y,z\ge 0$). This is the first use of symmetry. Because $f$ is dependent only on $\rho$, you can make further use of symmetry. In the $xy$-plane example, you might consider just $0\le y\le x$, for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few more hints:

The integral of $f(x,y,z)=3(x^2+y^2+z^2)$ over the whole ball with radius $5$ is
\begin{align}
I_1:=\int\limits_{x^2+y^2+z^2\le 25}3(x^2+y^2+z^2)\,dz\,dy\,dx\,.
\end{align}
This is easy to calculate using 3D polar coordinates. Looking at the picture
it is clear from symmetries that from $I_1$ you have to subtract six times the integral

\begin{align}
I_2=\int\limits_{x^2+y^2\le 9}\quad\int\limits_4^{\sqrt{25-x^2-y^2}} 3(x^2+y^2+z^2)\,dz\,dy\,dx
\end{align}
which covers the portions of the ball sticking out of the cube. The outer $dy\,dx$-integral in $I_2$ should be easy to calculate using 2D polar coordinates.

[image]

> \begin{align}I_1&=7500\pi\,,&I_2&=2\pi\int_0^3\int_4^{\sqrt{25-r^2}}3(r^2+z^2)\,r\,dz\,dr=\frac{1536\pi}{5}\,.\end{align}

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Is 3D polar coordinates are the same as spherical coordinated?

Comment: Yes. These are the ones you already used in OP.

Answer (score 0):

From the inequalities you wrote, using $\rho$ for $r$, parametrization of $K$ is
$$\rho\leq\min\left\{5,\frac{4}{|\cos\theta\sin\phi|},
\frac{4}{|\sin\theta\sin\phi|},
\frac{4}{|\cos\phi|}
 \right\}$$
$$0\leq\theta\leq2\pi$$
$$0\leq\phi\leq\pi$$